How can SHAP be utilized for interpretable analysis of Siamese neural networks?
When using the SHAP tool for explainable analysis of deep learning models, the explainer.shap_values function is designed to handle two-dimensional input data for interpretability analysis. However, for models like Siamese neural networks that have two sets of inputs, this results in a three-dimensional matrix as the input, leading to an error when attempting to use SHAP for analysis.Program error message 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\新建文件夹\predict.py", line 123, in 
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(Xtest)
File "C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\shap\explainers_kernel.py", line 266, in shap_values
raise DimensionError(emsg)
shap.utils._exceptions.DimensionError: Instance must have 1 or 2 dimensions!
I am interested in employing SHAP for interpretable analysis of neural networks with multi-dimensional inputs, with a focus on Siamese neural networks initially, and I would like to know if it's feasible to extend this to other neural networks that have three or more input channels. If this is achievable, what modifications would I need to make to my code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
